# Confused with nested views angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I've just came across this tutorial.  It's this particular app is what I'm looking for.   http://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router

However I want this particular view to be in the middle of my already existing app.  Is this is known as   nested views?  However when I tried to implement this app into my website...the page wouldn't load.  I think this is due to the routing at script.js?  Is it possible to use both $routeProvider and $Stateprovider?

```
//create our angular app and inject ngroute,nganimate and uirouter
var financeApp = angular.module('financeApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ui.router']);

 // configure our routes
  financeApp.config(function($routeProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {


   $routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/main.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/about.html',
     })

     // route for the contact page
     .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/contact.html',
     })

     .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
 })
});




$stateProvider

// route to show our basic form (/form)
.state('form', {
 url: '/form',
 templateUrl: 'form.html',
 controller: 'formController'
  })

   // nested states
   // each of these sections will have their own view
   // url will be nested (/form/profile)
   .state('form.profile', {
   url: '/profile',
   templateUrl: 'partials/form-profile.html'

 // url will be /form/interests
 .state('form.interests', {
url: '/interests',
templateUrl: 'form-interests.html'
})

 // url will be /form/payment
 .state('form.payment', {
url: '/payment',
templateUrl: 'form-payment.html'
 });

 // catch all route
 // send users to the form page 
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/profile');
  })
```

Basically I want a changeable view in the middle of one static page.  I'm not quite sure how to go about it.    Click on a button in the middle, takes you to another view in the middle, click on a button, takes you to another view in the middle. etc

This is my angularjs website [image: link]     Where the main image is...I would like there to be a form in the middle.

I am trying to achieve the following:  Please forgive the rudimentary drawing on MSpaint...

[image]

Comment: What your are talking about isn't necessarily a "nested view". You don't have to use ui-router for this unless you want to. Angular's built-in ng-view would work for this application.

Comment: Would it work for multiple pages? I want the middle of the area to be nearly identical to the app tutorial I just linked.  But it doesn't work because of my $route/nav bars link.

Comment: I don't think ngRoute and ui.router are meant to be used at the same time.  You can have a $routeProvider when using ui.router, but it's a shim to help migrate over to ui.router.  Maybe start by removing ngRoute and see where it goes from there.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888519/using-routeprovider-with-stateprovider

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what it is intended to do. Here's a pretty good tutorial using ngRoute, http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/routes.html. I wouldn't go with ui-router unless I had a need for it. Don't get me wrong, it is great but if you can do it with stock Angular, I would do that.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a button or link, you should be able to do something like:

```
<a href="#about">About</a>
```

Or if by clicking on the link, it calls code in a controller, you can use the $location service like:

```
$location.path('/about');
```

Of course that means you have to be injecting the $location service into your controller like,

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$location', function($location) {
   // other code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather have a visible view/form similar to the app I linked rather than just a button in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion though - use either `ngRoute` or `ui.router`, choose one. As for which one to use it's up to you to decide. I personally(biased) will go for `ui.router` since it provides much more features and is more elegant.

And then it is quite simple(clean and neat) if you are using `ui.router` when comes to nested states or nested views or both. To achieve it is quite simple. From the code that you have written, you have already `form` as parent state with its children, namely `form.profile`, `form.interest`, and `form.payment`. Now remember in the `form` state, you have a view which is `form.html` and it is governed by a controller called `formController`. Inside your `form.html`, you need to include a `ui-view` directive in order for `form`'s child state to reside there.

Something like this :

```
<!--This is your form.html-->
<div ui-view>
   <!--The child states of form will be populated here.-->
</div>
```

If you are still confused, here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zh0BrzSO9EzKTAe3Ywom?p=preview) that should help you with the understanding