# Clean URL or Removing Hasg tag from URL in angular ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

> I'm using angularJS to build a website and use angular-route library for view of different pages of website. my website is working well but there is a hash tag in url when i move on  different views. for removal of hash tag I'm using

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

> but this is not working on page refresh. My code is given below:-
>   **Index.html**

```
<body data-ng-app="myapp" data-ng-controller="myctrl">
<div data-ng-include=" 'pages/menu.html'"></div>
<div ng-view class="view-animate"></div>
<div data-ng-include=" 'pages/footer.php' "></div>

<body>
```

**app.js**

```
    'use-strict'
var tc = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

tc.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
    })
  .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    })
```

}]);

Comment: at the top of your index.html do you have <!doctype html> ?

Comment: yes i have <!DCTYPE html> at the top of index.html

Comment: have you included angular-route.js in your index.html ?

Comment: on reload f page this is not working. e.g : if I'm on www.mysitename.com/about on reload this page i got page not found error

Answer (score 1):

Use:-

```
<base href="/" />
```

And put this in your head tag :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use $stateProvider , $routeProvider not suggest by many Angularjs expert. And $stateProvider have more control over route then $routeprovider.

see

[Using $routeProvider with $stateProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888519/using-routeprovider-with-stateprovider)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `<!doctype html>` at the top of your index.html